# overflow just one element in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow

Is there a way, CSS or JavaScript to allow overflow of one element in a DIV, even if its parents overflow is hidden.

I've written a jQuery slider that hides slides by using `overflow: hidden`.

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="image.jpg" />
   <div class="text">
      THIS TEXT IS HIDDEN WHEN POSITIONED OUTSIDE OF .container
   </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px; height: 250px;
}
```

I need the image to overflow naturally though.

Comment: i think it's not possible unless you change something on your markup. Set up a fiddle showing the desired effect.

Comment: can you use javascript to set the width of container equal to the width of the image?

Comment: Not possible. CSS doesn't have "overflow: hidden except img". You'll have to revamp the markup and add extra containers.

Answer (score 14):

You should remove `position: relative;`. If you place it on the same element as `overflow: hidden;`, it will hide the element. If you really need it, try placing it on the parent of `.container` (higher in the tree than the element having `overflow: hidden`).

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/VtSHR/)
[Explanatory article](http://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent)

```css
#wrap { position: relative; }

.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 300px; height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px; left: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    Container
    <div class="text">Not hidden anymore when positioned outside of .container</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And this is an answer... how? removing position: relative would break the OP's slider.

Comment: @MarcB You might not have read the extended version of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Example

```
$('.text').each(function(){
   var t = $(this);                   // text div
   var c = t.closest('.container');   // container parent 
   var i = c.children('img:first');   // container image
   t.width(c.width());                // set text width = to container width
   c.width(i.width());                // set container width = to text width
});
```

*Note:*

1. *This does not take padding/margins/borders into affect, but is the basic logic you can use.*
2. *Setting the text width equal to the container width only gives it the appearance that the overflow is applied (you could also just set the text-div's width to 500px)*

Answer (score 0):

with declaring z-index in css you can use position absolute to do this.

```
.container{
   z-index:900;
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 500px; 
   height: 250px;
 }

 .container img{
   z-index:920;
   position:absolute;
 }
```

you can set margin for image if its position is not true;

Answer (score 0):

you cant set image popover with `position: static`

```
.container{
   z-index:900;
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 500px; 
   height: 250px;
 }

 .container img{
   z-index:920;
   position:static;
 }
```